# Android 9 device does not save network

Tags: wi-fi, networking

On an Android 9 tablet:

1. Settings
2. Use Wi-Fi
3. Add network
4. Enter an SSID, and select security None (the Wi-Fi does not require a password).
5. Tap Save

The network is not saved and the tablet does not connect to the Wi-Fi network. The Wi-Fi network works perfectly with half a dozen or so other devices.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What is the model name and manufacturer of the tablet?

Comment: @Robert Thank you for trying to help. It is this device: https://jltmobile.com/product/mt3010a-10-fully-rugged-tablet/ I have figured out - I need to go to Advanced options and select Yes for the hidden network option. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer my question per the suggestion of Andrew instead of deleting it.

The solution I found:

1. Tap Advanced options when adding a network
2. Select Yes for Hidden network

[image]

I think I missed the saved network when I posted my question. The network was saved on this tablet but it was on a separate list at the bottom:
[image]